# undefined variable foreach laravel

Tags: laravel

**view**

```html
@foreach($post as $ps)
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">
            <img src="{{asset('img/python.png')}}" class="circle" width="20" height="20">&nbsp;<b style="color:black;">{{ Auth::user()->name }}</b>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
            <center><img src="{{ str_replace('public/', '', $ps->image) }}" alt="" style="width: 100%;" height="320"></center>
        </div>
        <div class="card-footer text-muted">
            <b style="color:black;">{{ Auth::user()->email }}</b><br>
            {{$ps->caption}}
        </div>
    </div>
    <br><br>
@endforeach
```

**controller**

```php
public function index()
{
    $post=Post::all();

    // dd($id);
    return view('home', $post);
}
```

**error**

> post (View:
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\bima_1202174034\Modul5\resources\views\home.blade.php)

Comment: `return view('home', ['posts' => $posts]);` the array keys are what the variables will be named

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**you need to change your code**

```
public function index()
{
        $post = Post::all();

        return view('home', $post)  //This is not perfect way

        return view('home', compact('post'));//This is right way
}
```

Comment: you just write  return view('home', compact('post'));//This is right way

Comment: if you get your proper answer so please give upvote this answer. thank you so much..

Answer (score 2):

You must be use

```
public function index()
{
    $post=Post::all();
    return view('home', compact('post'));
}
```

or

```
 return view('home')->with('post', $post);
```

for good practice use

```
public function index()
{
    $posts = Post::all();
    return view('home', compact('posts'));
}
```

in view

```
@foreach($posts as $ps)
     //your logic 
@foreach
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to pass `variable` to `view` from `controller` but always use `compact` to pass `variable` from `controller` to `view` e.g

```
public function index()
{
        $post = Post::all();

        // dd($id);
        return view('home', compact('post'));
}
```

To know more about this kindly visit docs to read more about [Passing Data To Views](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/views#passing-data-to-views)

Thanks